# SQL Data Update Query About

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table named testlink and it has url and newtarget columns.

I would like to take the string expressions `https://domain1.com/` here in the url column and change all the data in the `newtarget` column to `https://domain1.com/search/?q=` pulled string expression.

So briefly;

url columns from `https://domain1.com/topic1`
will be changed to `https://domain1.com/search/?q=topic1` in the `newtarget` column

There are about 6 thousand different topics (lines) available.

Database: Mysql / Phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [REPLACE](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php)

```
UPDATE testlink 
SET newtarget = REPLACE(url,'https://domain1.com/','https://domain1.com/search/?q=')
```

> MySQL REPLACE() replaces all the occurrences of a substring within a
>   string.
>
> `REPLACE(str, find_string, replace_with)`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work out the way I wanted; https://prnt.sc/q3upe8
I want it that way; https://prnt.sc/q3upug

Comment: Check again, I remove a space in the `REPLACE(url,'https://domain1.com/',` but now is modified and tested, and it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally change the value, you can use string manipulations:

```
update t
    set url = concat(left(url, length(url) - length(substring_index(url, '/', -1))), 'q=', substring_index(url, '/', -1))
    where url like 'https://domain1.com/%';
```

This uses `substring_index()` to get the last part of the string (after the last `/`).  It uses `left()` to get the first part (based on the length of the last part) and then concatenates the values you want.

Of course, test this logic using a `SELECT` before implementing an `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thanks, it almost happened: https://prnt.sc/q3uxkp
How can I do it that way? Would you mind editing the query for me please?: https://prnt.sc/q3uxzu (I want this to happen.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL 8, then you'd be able to do that with [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).

For your example, this should work :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('https://domain1.com/topic1','(https:\/\/domain1\.com\/)(.+)','$1search/?q=$2')
```